# NSMutableArray order getting changed when using addObject: from NSDictionary using foreach loop

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary (self.dictMyDownloads) with values :

```
    {
  1: {
    id: "1",
    name: "Venue Details",
    url: "http://www.sapusers.org/event_files/3338_VENUE DETAILS KB.pdf",
    file_size: "97011"
  },
  2: {
    id: "2",
    name: "another filename",
    url: "test url 2",
    file_size: "4321"
  },
  3: {
    id: "3",
    name: "Map/Directions",
    url: "http://www.sapusers.org/event_files/3337_SAP UK Location Map HB.pdf",
    file_size: "429320"
  }
}
```

I am running this code to insert the dictionaries in the main dictionary into a nsmutablearray (self.mutArrMyDownloadsDetails) :

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in [self.dictMyDownloads allKeys]){
    [self.mutArrMyDownloadsDetails addObject:[self.dictMyDownloads objectForKey:dict]];
}
```

But when I display the result, the order of the dictionaries getting added in the array is getting changed.

This is the result log its showing:

```
    (
        {
        "file_size" = 97011;
        id = 1;
        name = "Venue Details";
        url = "http://www.sapusers.org/event_files/3338_VENUE DETAILS KB.pdf";
    },
        {
        "file_size" = 429320;
        id = 3;
        name = "Map/Directions";
        url = "http://www.sapusers.org/event_files/3337_SAP UK Location Map HB.pdf";
    },
        {
        "file_size" = 4321;
        id = 2;
        name = "another filename";
        url = "test url 2";
    }
)
```

I cannot understand where or what i am doing wrong. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: why u relying on sequence when you have key to access the objects of dictionary?

Comment: I think I can save the pdf using the id and retrieve the same using the id itself....i think that will not be a problem. The sequence doesn't really matter i think. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are not stored sequentially in an NSMutableDictnory and so you can not rely on the sequence they are shown in NSLog. Is it really necessary to use array there? I recommend to use only dictionary if possible.

Comment: actually i need to display the result in a uitableview, so that i can use it to save and display the pdf file using indexpath.row as the file name to save and btn.tag in each cell to display it.

Comment: You can save the content in a dictionary using the index number as key and the pdf file data as its value.

Comment: Each cell in the table has an Open Button. I am stting a tag for each button in the cellforrowatindex: method. And then on button tap i am calling a method where i am accessing the id of the dictionary in the array with button tag to display the pdf.

Comment: I think I can save the pdf using the id and retrieve the same using the id itself....i think that will not be a problem. The sequence doesn't really matter i think. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

another way is to create an NSArray from your NSMutableArray, by sorting it when your for loop is finished:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

NSArray *sortedArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.mutArrMyDownloadsDetails sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]];
```